# (*this)[i] after overloading [] operator?

Tags: c++, syntax

I overloaded the `[]` operator in my class.  Is there a nicer way to call this function from within my class other than `(*this)[i]`?

Comment: Near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681746/2d-matrix-and-overloading-operator-ugly-syntax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add function `at(size_t i)` and use this function.

**EDIT**: If you actively using stl avoid semantic inconsistence: in `std::vector operator[]` does not check if index is valid, but `at(..)` check and could throw `std::out_of_range` exception. I think in project with more stl similar behavior will expected from your class.

Maybe this name is not best one for this function.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you could use `operator[](i)`.

Answer (score 7):

Not nice, but explicit:

```
this->operator[](i)
```

If you find that you need to do this a lot, create an At() function which does exactly what operator[] does. You can then say:

```
this->At(i)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd advocate adding an 'at' that does *exactly* the same as operator[]. It departs from the precedent set by the standard.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend duplicating the code (I doubt that's what Neil is suggesting), but there wouldn't be anything wrong with having operator[]() call the at() or At().

Comment: You don't need to put "this->" in front of a method call.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a reasonable compromise:

```
T& me = *this;

// ...

me[i];
```

Comment: Would be nice if C++ had a built in special type for *this. PHP has "self" but that's not quite the same either. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: According to Stroustup, 'this' probably would have been a reference except that references came along too late in the evolution of C++.

Comment: Damn shame he didn't go back and rewrite everything to be reference-centric when that happened. It would have been a far better language.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are acessing something from within your own class, why not just use a private function, named as you see fit:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        SomeType& Item(int index) { /* return a value */ }
    public:
        SomeType& operator[](int index) { return Item(index); }
        void SomeFunction(void);
}

void myClass::SomeFunction(void)
{
    SomeType localVar = Item(42); // internal access
}

int main(int argCount, char ** argList)
{
    MyClass myClass;
    SomeType x;

    x = myClass[42]; // external access

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That example is a little overkill for your point, but thanks :) +1 for effort

Comment: Haha true. I just didn't know where to stop : )

Answer (score 0):

`this->[i]` doesn't even compile. The only other option is `this->operator[](i)`.

Comment: You don't need "this->" in front of a method call.