# How do I access a C++ subscript operator from within the class in which it resides?

Tags: c#, c++, subscript-operator

Where, ClassA has an operator as such, that returns ClassB:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA();
    ClassB &operator[](int index);
}
```

If I want to access said operator from within ClassA's constructor, as so:

```
ClassA::ClassA()
{
    // How do I access the [] operator?
}
```

At the moment, as a work-around I'm just using a method called GetAtIndex(int index) which the [] operator calls, and so does the constructor.

It would be nice if I could access it in the same as as C# works:

```
// Note: This is C#
class ClassA
{
   ClassB this[int index]
   {
       get { /* ... */ }
       set { /* ... */ }
   }

   void ClassA()
   {
       this[0] = new ClassB();
   }
}
```

**Note:** I'm using g++

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702003/thisi/702015

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following

```
(*this)[0] = ...
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
this->operator[](0) = ...
```

or:

```
(*this)[0] = ...
```

But the syntax is a little awkward.  I usually make another method called `get` and use that, e.g.:

```
ClassB& get(size_t index) {
    return this->operator[](0); // or something more direct
}
```

Then when you want to use it you can just say:

```
this->get(0) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ClassA::ClassA()
 {
     this->operator[]( someindex ) = whatever;
 }
```

But make sure that whatever member data the operator may depend on is fully constructed before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, not sure if it's useful...

```
ClassA::ClassA()
{
    ClassA &_this = *this;
    _this[0] = someValue;
    _this[1] = someValue;
    _this[2] = someValue;
    _this[3] = someValue;
    _this[4] = someValue;
}
```

Comment: The third line should be "ClassA& _this = *this;" so you aren't making a copy of this.

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways:

```
( *this ) [ index ] or this -> operator [ ] ( index )
```